# How to control folder option with C# or registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry, windows-explorer

I am developing a C# Application and I need to enable/disable the *Hide protected system files* option in folder settings via C#. It would also be useful to know what changes are made in the registry when I check or uncheck that check box in the Folder Options dialog.

Comment: [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can be used to track registry (and file system) changes by other programs.

Answer (score 3):

For current user:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

...

```
const string keyName = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced";
int enabled = 1; // 0 to disable
Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ShowSuperHidden", enabled, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```